# Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made an app in Ruby on Rails and now I want to get it hosted.  However, they require that I use MySQL and I set it up using sqLite3.  Is there any way to convert it to use MySQL?

Comment: Do you need to migrate data from sqlite?  Or do you just want to start using MySQL on a fresh database from here on out?

Comment: The Rails 6+ way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72572767/1136887

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### Step 0

To be safe, I recommend experimenting a bit with this technique in a virtual machine.  Save yourself a bunch of heartache and build a virtual machine, check out your code, and have a safe playground that you can throw away if tragedy strikes.

### Step 1

Make a backup copy of your database.yml file.

(from your application root)

`cp config/database.yml config.database.yml.sqlite3`

### Step 2

Make a backup copy of your data

For Rails 3, install the YAML DB gem: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db
by running

```
gem install yaml_db
```

and then add to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'yaml_db'
```

For Rails 2.x install the YAML DB plugin:

`script/plugin install git://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db.git`

Run the dump task

`rake db:dump`

### Step 3

Update your config/database.yml file.  You will find entries like

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

Change them to

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: **myapp_development**
  pool: 5
  username: **root**
  password: **supersecretpassword**
  **socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock**
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: **myapp_test**
  pool: 5
  username: **root**
  password: **supersecretpassword**
  socket: **/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock**

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: **myapp_production**
  pool: 5
  username: **root**
  password: **supersecretpassword**
  socket: **/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock**
```

Be sure to update the values surrounded by asterix as appropriate for your platform!  The socket value is only good for Mac OSX using MacPorts.  Most flavors of linux do not require this value.

### Step 5

If you have some errors in the following step, you might have to install the mysql or mysql2 gem:

```
sudo gem install mysql
```

or

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

Have rake create your database

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
```

### Step 6

Use YamlDb to reload your data into MySql

`rake db:load`

Comment: You really should use db:schema:load instead of db:migrate for creating new databases.

Comment: actually, why do you need to use Virtual Machine?  I thought you can commit your whole Rails project folder to Git or Mercurial or SVN, or even copy the whole folder to a different one, and all data including the sqlite DB data is there, able to be used as a Rails app again.

Comment: I followed this and the process seemed to go smoothly but now I'm having a mysql2 syntax error. I've posted it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406016/mysql2error-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax

Comment: For those who didn't know like me: in rails 3.x, you can install the gem by adding "gem 'yaml_db'" to Gemfile and then do "bundle install"

Comment: @動靜能量 - You generally aren't going to be committing your database to version control. And if you are - you would only have a development one in there anyways ( I would hope! ) After you run something in prod - Prod will have it's own database that wouldn't be in version control anyhow as you should be deploying it through some packaging system or a deploy key and it won't write back to Git.

Comment: I had (am) suffering a lot with different dev environments to production. I have SQlite for dev and MySQL for production and am learning the hard way the using find_by_sql with boolean values has unpredictable results

Comment: update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411673/1847899  - https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2

Comment: Stop using SQLite for development... http://streaming.nfm.id.au/stop-using-sqlite-for-rails-development-ndash/

Comment: Can you update this post please? Step2: for rails 3: command line is: gem install yaml_db, then add: gem 'yaml_db' in your Gemfile, then the rest of your comments

Answer (score 7):

As long as you have not written any SQL statements that run in sqlLite3 and not MySQL (which you won't have if all your database access is via ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord migrations) then all you need to do is change the database adapter in your database.yml config file.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to run rake db:migrate in the new environment (but that will be true of any new environment whether it is a different database engine or not.)

Answer (score 6):

Check [Taps](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/).  I've successfully converted a Mysql database to Postgres with it --it should support SQLite.

Edit: Including working link from cony's comment here.

Comment: I had to do this recently, Taps worked like a charm, check out this blog entry for examples:

http://adamblog.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/

Comment: taps is an awesome utility, definitely worth to check it out

Comment: link broken, http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/ seems to work

Answer (score 5):

If there's no data to migrate, simply update database.yml and run 'rake db:schema:load' in the new environment. (NOT db:migrate which should only be used for incremental migrations!)

Answer (score 5):

```
myproject  user$ cd
user   $ rails new myproject -d mysql
```

Say 'no' for all question but for `Overwrite .../myproject/config/*database.yml*? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]` say 'yes'.

Comment: Don't forget the gemfile