# What the difference between mysql and mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I used to work with the `mysql` gem, but often nowadays I hear about the `mysql2` gem. Also, it is included in the **Gemfile** by default in `Rails 3.0.x`.

What is the difference and advantages of using the `mysql2` gem?

Comment: "included into Gemfile by default"? I don't see that in 3.2.8

Comment: @KMC, year ago it was included? :)

Comment: I too am after a differences list, I hit one diff that was answered elsewhere re `each_hash` being removed. It would be nice to know what other changes I should search my code base for.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Here's a quote from the [mysql2 gem page](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2):

> Yeah… but why?
>
> Someone: Dude, the Mysql gem works
>   fiiiiiine.
>
> Me: It sure does, but it only hands
>   you nil and strings for field values.
>   Leaving you to convert them into
>   proper Ruby types in Ruby-land - which
>   is slow as balls.
>
> Someone: OK fine, but do_mysql can
>   already give me back values with Ruby
>   objects mapped to MySQL types.
>
> Me: Yep, but its API is considerably
>   more complex and can be ~2x slower.

Answer (score 12):

mysql2 is very much faster than the mysql gem. Also, apart from being effective, it also has more features and is more fun, just like Ruby on Rails.

Comment: More features? Last I checked it can't even do prepared statements!

Comment: I am also surprised there is no prepared statement support, although it looks like it's almost there as of [five days ago](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/pull/289).