# Ruby mysql gem error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have install the mysql gem but am falling at the first hurdle:

```
 initialize': wrong number of arguments(4 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from open.rb:14:in `new' 
 from open.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Is the result from this code:

```
 require 'mysql'

 db = Mysql.new('localhost','root','','test')
 puts db
```

I was following the code from this tutorial:

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_mysql_tutorial.html

It just looks like the new method is not going to accept 4 arguments. I have no idea why. Mysql.new creates a new object just fine.

Comment: Sorry yeh just removed that #. That wasn't there when I got the error. It just seems the new method is not happy with 4 arguments.

Comment: Let me guess: you're using Mac OS X Leopard (or Lion), right? ) If that's the story, check [this article](http://thinlight.org/2010/05/12/how-to-install-ruby-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/), it should help you. )

Comment: I'm on Mountain Lion (10.7). Just tried that fix but unfortunately I am still getting that error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Mysql2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Then:

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
results = client.query("show databases")
results.each do |row|
  puts row["Database"]
end
```

You can find more information in the [gem documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.11/frames)

HTH!

Comment: Just been trying mysql2 but now I get: '`require': dlopen(/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)'

Comment: Solved! Using mysql2, your code and this little tip. Thanks! http://rorguide.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing that tip. I'm sure it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Is line 14 the line where you declare `db = Mysql.new('localhost','root','','test')`?

I've just opened `irb`, installed the gem, copied your line and it worked just fine - it returned me a Mysql object as expected.

Can you try do the same via `irb`? Btw, I recommend you to install the `mysql2` gem instead. Here is an explanation about the why: [What the difference between mysql and mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411551/what-the-difference-between-mysql-and-mysql2-gem)

Comment: 1.9.3-p0 :002 > require 'mysql'
     => true 
     1.9.3-p0 :003 > Mysql.new('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db')
     ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(4 for 0)
 from (irb):3:in `initialize'
 from (irb):3:in `new'
 from (irb):3
 from /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'

Comment: Sadly I get the same error in irb. It just won't accept the 4 arguments. Thanks for taking the time to try! What's your setup? I am running OS X Mountain Lion

Comment: I'm also on Lion. However, my Ruby version is 1.9.2. Can you try to use gem `mysql2` instead? You can find it's docs here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.3/frames

Comment: Yep I'm now trying the mysql2 gem but getting a new error: `require': dlopen(/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysq‌​l2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)'

Comment: Solved! sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib from: http://rorguide.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html