# What the difference between mysql and ruby-mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to install `mysql` or `mysql2` gem but it's not working.

I have already installed `ruby-mysql`.

Does this gem have the same features as the `mysql2` gem?

Comment: What "no working" means? It throws some errors? How do you know that it's not working? ;)

Comment: The github site for `ruby-mysql` is mum about any deficiencies. So it's unclear how to answer your question. You could email the author from the github site and ask. It would be good to know what kind of error you hit attempting the `mysql` and `mysql2` gems. They should work.

Comment: need more clarification, how are you trying to install it? does it install cleanly? what version of ruby? Is the error in the installation or the use of the gem?

Comment: @Doon ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0] error on install

Comment: i try to see other post about mysql2 gem installation but even those could not help me

Comment: and what is the error on install?  the logs from the gem build will normally tell you what is wrong

Comment: i got this error: *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.

i read usually you got that by using wrong msql_config path but my config path is right:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql` is offered as gem for easy installation using RubyGems. It wraps unmodified tmtm's `mysql-ruby` extension into a proper gem. Please note that tmtm (Tomita Mashahiro) has deprecated development of this extension and only update it for bug fixes.

Read definition of [mysql gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql), and [ruby-mysql gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-mysql).

Read difference from `mysql`, and `mysql2` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411551/what-the-difference-between-mysql-and-mysql2-gem).

Comment: Yes, ruby-mysql is better

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the adapter:

```
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter', '~> 0.0.3'
```