# Should I use the mysql or mysql2 gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby, cucumber

I need to connect to a MySQL database.  I've found a gem called "mysql" and one called "mysql2". I tried installing and using both gems and got a message like this:

```
cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
C:/Automation/ta-rb5-portal-cuke/features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:2:in
`require'
C:/Automation/ta-rb5-portal-cuke/features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>
```

Which gem should I use and what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Ruby 2.1.7.

Comment: You probably want to use [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) or [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) to connect to your database. Using the low-level driver is extremely messy.

Comment: also try loading these gems via [bundler](http://bundler.io/) and not relying on system installs (such as 'gem install mysql').

Comment: This seems awful close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5411551/128421

Comment: The short answer to what you actually asked in the title is: you should use mysql2.  But normally you'd use Sequel or ActiveRecord as higher level abstractions, with mysql2.  And that doesn't answer your installation problems, which you might have with mysql2 as well.  Ruby on Windows is painful.