# How do I change my database from SQLite to MYSQL in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I know that you have to change the database.yml but I don't know what to change it to and how to download MYSQL and all of that jazz.

Comment: Which OS are you running? You'll also need to edit your Gemfile.

Comment: Official docs: [Active Record Migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_name_here
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Command line:

```
bundle install
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Of course MySQL needs to be installed.

If you're creating a new project:

```
rails new app_name_here -d mysql
```

Comment: What do you mean by my instance?

Comment: by instance I mean your own settings

Comment: It says thatt I can't use mysql 0.3.6
What is an earlier version that is 0.2.x

Comment: Can we change the database from sqlite to mysql after we have created the application? I forgot to put `-d mysql` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when trying to use the mysql2 gem with Rails 3.0.9.
When I ran `rake db:create` after installing the mysql2 gem, it gave me these warnings:

> WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.6) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
>
> WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x

To specify that you only want to use the 0.2.x versions of mysql2, edit your Gemfile so that

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

becomes

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.1'
```

Comment: This is intended to addresses Planetpluto's comment under tybro0103's answer. I would have responded with another comment but it appears that I don't have enough privilege points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 6 a command has been added to do this automatically.

```
$ rails db:system:change --to=mysql
    conflict  config/database.yml
Overwrite /home/jim/Rails projects/myapp/config/database.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] y
       force  config/database.yml
        gsub  Gemfile
        gsub  Gemfile
```

Ref.: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-has-added-a-way-to-change-the-database-of-the-app