# Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql-error-1064, mysql2

I just used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql) to switch my rails app db from sqlite3 to mysql2 and that seemed to work out properly.

But when I start up my app I'm now getting this:

```
A ActionView::Template::Error occurred in pages#dashboard:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 1) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 1: SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE (archived == 1) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `log'
```

Not sure where to look to get this working properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have this error when I navigate to rails admin and try to edit one of my users.do you have any  ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Notice single = vs ==
WHERE (archived = 1)
```

---

**Update**
Ended up doing

```
scope :is_archived, where('archived != ?', 1)
scope :not_archived, where('archived = ?', 1)
```

This worked great. Thanks!

Comment: so like this: ```scope :not_archived, where('archived == ?', 1)```??

Comment: scope :not_archived, where('archived = ?', 1)

Comment: alternately, scope :not_archived, where(:archived => 1)

Comment: what about when i want to do: ```scope :is_archived, where('archived != ?', 1)```?

Comment: Damn, sorry, I was only looking at the mysql syntax. I cannot confirm for the ruby construct, but I do know that `==` in mysql context is incorrect.