# yaml_db Not Working When Dumping the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, yaml, dump

I'm trying to convert  my rubyonrails project from sqlite3 to MySQL by following:

- [Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql)
- https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

Here is the command line log:

```
plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ gem install yaml_db
Successfully installed yaml_db-0.2.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for yaml_db-0.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for yaml_db-0.2.3...

plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ gem list | grep yaml_db
yaml_db (0.2.3)

plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ rake db:data:dump
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:data:dump'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ rake db:dump
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:dump'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$
```

and my OS info:

```
plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ uname -a
Linux sos 2.6.38-15-generic-pae #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 22 11:48:17 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
plee@sos:~/rubyonrails/blog$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out why.  The installation requires two steps:

Step 1. Install the `gem` `yaml_db`:

`gem install yaml_db`

Step 2. Add it to the `Gemfile` under your project home director

`gem 'yaml_db'`

Then we can run `rake db:dump` without any problems.

Comment: This helps, but I'm still getting the following error...

rake db:data:dump

rake aborted!

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
(erb):80:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongoid-3.0.23/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:40:in `load_yaml'