# Ruby on Rails: SQLite to MySQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I'm begginer at Rails. I want to deploy my project at heroku.com. I use SqLite, but heroku doesn't support it. So, I try to move my project to MySQL. I did this instructions :[Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql)

But, heroku says something like this: we're sorry, but something went wrong. Can you help me?

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem "will_paginate", :git => "https://github.com/p7r/will_paginate.git", :branch => "rails3"
gem 'yaml_db', :git => 'git://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db.git'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "0761"
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "0761"

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "0761"
```

And here is my logs:

```
2013-03-26T13:11:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:11:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:11:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-03-26T13:11:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-26T13:11:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T13:11:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-26T13:11:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T13:11:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T13:11:38+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:33768
2013-03-26T13:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:11:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=33768
2013-03-26T13:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:11:39] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T13:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:11:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T13:11:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-26T13:11:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 13:11:59 +0000
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.8ms)
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=304ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 136ms
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (51.2ms)
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1283683624385357693_38228720'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb__3258341653661936969_33454780'
2013-03-26T13:12:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=16ms connect=35ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-03-26T13:25:17+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7a646d5 by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-26T13:25:51+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-26T13:25:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 59776`
2013-03-26T13:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59776
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=59776
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T13:25:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T13:25:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 13:25:59 +0000
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (29.7ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (26.4ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3050356598751074094_29958360'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb___3316497000915670487_28099760'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=254ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=0
root@Nikita-PC:/home/nikita/rails/invent# heroku open
Opening ancient-cliffs-5913... done
root@Nikita-PC:/home/nikita/rails/invent# heroku logs
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1283683624385357693_38228720'
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:11:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb__3258341653661936969_33454780'
2013-03-26T13:12:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=16ms connect=35ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-03-26T13:25:17+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7a646d5 by nikskalkin@gmail.com
2013-03-26T13:25:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-26T13:25:51+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-26T13:25:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 59776`
2013-03-26T13:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:25:55+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59776
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=59776
2013-03-26T13:25:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-03-26T13:25:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T13:25:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 13:25:59 +0000
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (29.7ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (26.4ms)
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3050356598751074094_29958360'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb___3316497000915670487_28099760'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=254ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-26T13:26:00+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-03-26T13:25:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-03-26T13:25:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-03-26T13:25:54+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-26 13:25:54] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-03-26T13:26:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-03-26T13:26:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-26T13:26:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 46.72.99.61 at 2013-03-26 13:29:30 +0000
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (6.5ms)
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <ul class="nav">
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:                   <li><%= link_to "Меню", menu_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:                <!--<li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>-->
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:                   <li><%= link_to "Заказ", "#" %></li>
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:32:in `authenticate_with_salt'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in `signed_in?'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    <% if signed_in? %>
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `user_from_remember_token'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:                    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная", home_path %></li>
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3050356598751074094_29958360'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__menu_html_erb___3316497000915670487_28099760'
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-03-26T13:29:30+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-cliffs-5913.herokuapp.com fwd="46.72.99.61" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=643
```

**Update**
I can use only MySQL. My project is testing task for internship of one company i'm looking for. And they said me to use MySql in project.

Comment: just use `pg`. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Comment: Spend some time on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book to get a better handle on rails configuration, and working with heroku; will save you a lot of trouble over the long term :-)

Answer (score 4):

Heroku is really designed to run PostgreSQL as its database engine, not MySQL.  You actually have the postgresql gem installed (`pg`).  The error you're getting is related to accessing the database (specifically the `users` table).

While it is possible to run MySQL on Heroku as a new user I'd recommend just working with postgresql instead, as it's much easier to set up and you won't have to worry about installing additional add-ons to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Where are you hosting your MySQL database?**  Make sure you db server has allowed remote access from Heroku.  Amazon (AWS) is best solution once setup properly.

If you are hosting the MySQL db on your local machine for production then you will need to **make sure Heroku's servers have remote access back to your computer for production**.

In your Gemfile remove these lines and replace with example below.

- `gem 'pg'`
- `gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'`
- `gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"`

I also would strongly recomend checking out https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro & http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised?view=comments

**To Setup MySQL on AWS:**

1. Update Gemfile with correct db gems
2. Update database.yml connection settings
3. Install Heroku toolbelt https://toolbelt.heroku.com/
4. Sign up for AWS hosted MySQL  http://aws.amazon.com/rds/
5. Amazon requires you to grant access from both your local machine’s WAN IP & you will also need to grant Heroku’s application servers authorized access for production.

   - SignIn to AWS via http://console.aws.amazon.com/
   - Go to "Services" > "RDS"
   - Under left menu "Navigation/Databases" > "DB Security Groups" > "default"
   - Add CIDR/IP: #.#.#.# (your local pc ip  http://www.whatsmyip.us/)
   - Add EC2 Security Group (this is heroku aws id)

     - aws account id: "098166147350"
     - ec2 security group: "default"
6. Setup AWS RDS MySQL Database on Heroku

   - Confirm Heroku is Granted AWS RDS Remote Access

     - `$ cd myAppDir`
     - `$ heroku login`
     - `$ heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`
     - `$ heroku addons:add amazon_rds url=mysql2://masteruser:pass@dbinstance.123endpoint321.amazonaws.com/databasename`
     - `$ heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`
     - Confirm New Database Settings

**Gemfile** ~ Don't forget `$ bundle install` & `$ bundle update`

```
# ===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===
group :development do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
# ===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===
group :production do
  # gem 'pg'
  gem 'mysql2'
end
# ===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===
group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # gem 'mysql2'
end
# ===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===~===
```

**database.yml** ~ Examples of each type of db connection.

```
# AWS RDS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: dbinstance.123endpoint789.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  database: appdb_dev
  pool: 5
  username: masterusername
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# MySQL localhost ~~~~~~~~
# development:
#   adapter: mysql2
#   encoding: utf8
#   database: erics_rails_app_dev
#   pool: 5
#   username: root
#   password:
#   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# HEROKU ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Note: On Heroku production this (over)written on deployment.
production:
  adapter: pg
  database: localhost
  timeout: 5000
# ORIGINAL TEST ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

MySQL WorkBench Settings ~ http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

```
* hostname = dbinstance.123endpoint789.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
* user = masterusername
* pass = password
* port = 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a mysql addon for the app?

Heroku provides you with a Postgres database by default but if you want to use another database type aka mysql then you will need to use an addon. There may be a free solution in the addons i'm not sure.

When you deploy your application to Heroku they override your database.yml file pointing it to the correct database url.

Answer (score 0):

First heroku provides you a PostgreSQL database for your app, edit your Gemfile

and add gem 'pg'

also it uses thin as server so add

gem 'thin'

chage your Database.yml as for all enviromments

```
adapter: PostgreSQL
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "0761"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mysql gem from your production environment. Heroku doesn't support sqlite databases. Use postgres in production. Your gemfile should look something like this:

```
group :production do
  gem "pg" # move your pg gem inside here
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

Change your gemfile to reflect the above, run `$ bundle` to bundle then new gems, add and commit your changes and push them to heroku.

This will allow you to use sqlite in development and test, and postgresql in production, which heroku requires.