# Ruby on Rails: Rakefile not found, Rake suddenly stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently decided to convert my app's database from SQLite to MySQL and apache (using xampp). I installed xampp with no issues and I followed [Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql) SO to prepare my app for the switch. I then attempted **rake db:migrate** and instantly received this:

```
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

I back tracked made sure the MySql gem was installed and tried another rake command, no luck. I uninstalled ruby on rails and re-installed, created a fresh app, and still no luck. In fact, as soon as I try to use any rake command after re-installing I get that error. I have checked to make sure the rakefile exists. I have no idea what is going on and I couldn't find anyone with the same issue.

the rake commands were working fine for weeks. At some point in the last 24 hours I messed it up somehow.

One other point of interest, i first installed db explorer before xammp but wasn't able to get it to run.

EDIT: Fixed issue by uninstalling rails, backing up and deleting all apps, deleting .gem folder, removing all global paths. Then re-installed with **RailsInstaller**, set user Paths, went to **rake** directory and **rake** command did not return the perpetrating message. I then created a new app with MySql2 and merged in my original app...

I am still no closer to understanding why rake suddenly stopped working. Therefore, I'm leaving this SO up in case I or another user discovers the cause.

Comment: Is this on a remote serer or local server?
Are you running the command from the root directory of your app?

Comment: Local server. I have it in my Path so I should be able to run it successfully from any directory. Although I have tried going to the directory with the same results.

Comment: Looks like your description attempted hyperlink to somewhere, but it's broken.