# Does Ruby on Rails support DB server by itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am beginner of Ruby on Rails.
I made first demo project and run by these commands

```
rails new demo
rails server
```

And It does work well.
I haven't installed any apache or mysql server like XAMPP, but my demo project worked.
Now I want to know if ruby on rails support database server by itself.
If not, should I install new database server like XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `config/database.yml` you will see the default is using `sqllite` which is installed in your system that is why the system up, and you can see in your gem file that `sqllite3` gem is exist which is the adapter that connect you to the database, once you changed the configuration for `database.yml` to use `postgres` for example and add the `pg` gem the app will fail to start as it couldn't connect to `postgres` as its not installed or its not up in your machine

check also this answer, it will clear a lot for you [Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you mean ruby provide sqllite db by default?
And if i want to use mysql server as db, how to do it? Then should i install mysql db server?

Comment: Yes, you will need to do 3 things, 1- install mysql in your machien, 2- install mysql gem, 3- change your database configuration to use mysql,

Comment: check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql

Comment: ok I understand, btw, ruby provide apache server by itself, i think.
And how do you think about that?

Comment: apache is a web server not database