# Ruby On Rails data migration from sqlite3 to mysql regarding to many to many relations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, has-and-belongs-to-many, data-migration

I have a `sqlite3` database in my `rails` app which has a `development.sqlite3` file. I want to convert the database to `mysql`.Here are the steps I take but still I have problems :

1.First I add and install `gem 'seed_dump'` to add the data into my `seed.rb` (By running `rake db:seed:dump`) because I really need to migrate my data .

2.Change the `database.yml` configuration to `mysql` setting.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: MyDB
  username: root
  password: ****
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: MyDB
  username: root
  password: ****
```

3.Run `rails db:create` then `rails db:schema:load`.

4.Then loading the data from seed by running `rake db:seed:dump`

The problem is my many to many relations data (which has a table in db schema ) can't be imported in mysql from my seed.rb.

The thing I wanna know is that is there any other safe way to migrate my data from `sqlite3` to `mysql` instead of writing them into `seed.rb` and then read them ?

Comment: ideally if you have a join table and you have your `seed.rb`, then the data from the join table should be written when saving your objects which have foreign keys to that table ... right?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Yes and this gem creates a HABTM like thing in seed.rb which when I load seed it gets error!

Comment: include the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was looking for another way to resolve the issue I've found what is declared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql). I followed the steps facing to another error of `mysql` : `Data is too long for column summary` . To skip this error I turned off `mysql strict mode` like this in `database.yml`:

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: myDB
  username: root
  password: ****
  host: localhost
  strict: false


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: myDB
  username: root
  password: **** 
  host: localhost
  strict: false
```

This solution is more clear than using `gem 'seed_dump'` which has problems with `has and belongs to many` relations!